# verify ownership on all files and directories associated with packages

Tags: package-management, rpm, ownership

In the Redhat, we can verify ownership on all files and directories associated with packages by using the following command:

```
# rpm -Va | grep '^......U'
```

Is there any equivalent command for Ubuntu?
I know that `debsums` is equivalent to `rpm -Va`, but I don't understand meaning of `grep '^......U'`.

Answer (score 1):

If the `deb` package is still beneath `/var/cache/apt/archives/`, then you can use `dpkg -c <packagename>` to list the contents of the package. Example output for package apt-file_2.5.1_all.deb (I'm on a Debian system right now):

```
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2012-06-03 10:32 ./
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2012-06-03 10:32 ./etc/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2012-06-03 10:32 ./etc/apt/
-rw-r--r-- root/root      2144 2012-06-03 10:32 ./etc/apt/apt-file.conf
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2012-06-03 10:32 ./etc/bash_completion.d/
-rw-r--r-- root/root       748 2012-06-03 10:32 ./etc/bash_completion.d/apt-file
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2012-06-03 10:32 ./usr/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2012-06-03 10:32 ./usr/bin/
-rwxr-xr-x root/root     10584 2012-06-03 10:32 ./usr/bin/diffindex-download
-rwxr-xr-x root/root      8762 2012-06-03 10:32 ./usr/bin/diffindex-rred
-rwxr-xr-x root/root     23919 2012-06-03 10:32 ./usr/bin/apt-file
-rwxr-xr-x root/root      6437 2012-06-03 10:32 ./usr/bin/rapt-file
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2012-06-03 10:32 ./usr/share/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2012-06-03 10:32 ./usr/share/apt-file/
-rw-r--r-- root/root       558 2012-06-03 10:32 ./usr/share/apt-file/apt-file-update.update-notifier
-rwxr-xr-x root/root        98 2012-06-03 10:32 ./usr/share/apt-file/do-apt-file-update
-rwxr-xr-x root/root       370 2012-06-03 10:32 ./usr/share/apt-file/is-cache-empty
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2012-06-03 10:32 ./usr/share/man/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2012-06-03 10:32 ./usr/share/man/man1/
-rw-r--r-- root/root      2628 2012-06-03 10:32 ./usr/share/man/man1/apt-file.1.gz
-rw-r--r-- root/root       905 2012-06-03 10:32 ./usr/share/man/man1/diffindex-download.1.gz
-rw-r--r-- root/root       646 2012-06-03 10:32 ./usr/share/man/man1/diffindex-rred.1.gz
-rw-r--r-- root/root      1023 2012-06-03 10:32 ./usr/share/man/man1/rapt-file.1.gz
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2012-06-03 10:32 ./usr/share/doc/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2012-06-03 10:32 ./usr/share/doc/apt-file/
-rw-r--r-- root/root       401 2012-06-02 18:50 ./usr/share/doc/apt-file/README
-rw-r--r-- root/root       464 2012-06-02 18:50 ./usr/share/doc/apt-file/copyright
-rw-r--r-- root/root      8634 2012-06-03 10:28 ./usr/share/doc/apt-file/changelog.gz
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2012-06-03 10:32 ./var/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2012-06-03 10:32 ./var/cache/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2012-06-03 10:32 ./var/cache/apt/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2012-06-03 10:32 ./var/cache/apt/apt-file/
```

You can now check the permissions and set them accordingly.

[This site](http://sysadminnotebook.blogspot.de/2012/06/how-to-reset-folder-permissions-to.html) has a script (printed below) that you could use to re-set the permissions according to the packages present on your system.
To limit the scope of the script to a single `.deb` package, copy the package in question from `/var/cache/apt/archives/` to another folder and put that folder in the `ARCHIVE_DIR` variable of the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Restores file permissions for all files on a debian system for which .deb
# packages exist.
#
# Author: Larry Kagan <me at larrykagan dot com>
# Since 2007-02-20
ARCHIVE_DIR=/var/cache/apt/archives/
PACKAGES=`ls $ARCHIVE_DIR`
cd /
function changePerms()
{
CHOWN="/bin/chown"
CHMOD="/bin/chmod"
PERMS=`echo $1 | sed -e 's/--x/1/g' -e 's/-w-/2/g' -e 's/-wx/3/g' -e 's/r--/4/g' -e 's/r-x/5/g' -e 's/rw-/6/g' -e 's/rwx/7/g' -e 's/---/0/g'`
PERMS=`echo ${PERMS:1}`
OWN=`echo $2 | /usr/bin/tr '/' '.'`
PATHNAME=$3
PATHNAME=`echo ${PATHNAME:1}`
echo -e "CHOWN: $CHOWN $OWN $PATHNAME"
result=`$CHOWN $OWN $PATHNAME`
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
echo -e $result
fi
echo -e "CHMOD: $CHMOD $PERMS $PATHNAME"
result=`$CHMOD $PERMS $PATHNAME`
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
echo -e $result
fi
}
for PACKAGE in $PACKAGES;
do
if [ -d $PACKAGE ]; then
continue;
fi
echo -e "Getting information for $PACKAGE\n"
FILES=`/usr/bin/dpkg -c "${ARCHIVE_DIR}${PACKAGE}"`
for FILE in "$FILES";
do
echo "$FILE" | awk '{print $1"\t"$2"\t"$6}' | while read line;
do
changePerms $line
done
done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

From [`man rpm`](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/rpm.8.html):

> The format of the output is a string of 8 characters, a possible "**c**"
>   denoting a configuration file, and then the file name. Each of the 8
>   characters denotes the result of a comparison of attribute(s) of the
>   file to the value of those attribute(s) recorded in the database. A
>   single "**.**" (period) means the test passed, while a single "**?**"
>   indicates the test could not be performed (e.g. file permissions
>   prevent reading). Otherwise, the (mnemonically emBoldened) character
>   denotes failure of the corresponding `--verify` test:
>
> **S** file **S**ize differs
>   ...
>   **U** **U**ser ownership differs

`U` in the sixth column of output indicates that the user ownership has changed (hence the five `.` in your `grep`).

I couldn't find anything similar in `debsums` or the various `dpkg` utilities.

I wonder if this is even possible with Debian packaging, since:

1. No matter who owned the files when creating the package, for installation they are owned by `root:root`. Only the modes remain intact.
2. Ownership is set using a `chmod` in the `postinst` script (e.g., `nslcd`).

The only way to do this would be using some sort of IDS, such as AIDE or OSSEC.